# Connection between Tehillim 22 and Purim?

Tags: purim, tehilim-psalms, song-poetry, faith-bitachon-emunah

A few years ago, I started hearing around Purim-time the song "Keli, keli, lamah azavtani" - ק-לי ק-לי, למה עזבתני, which comes from [Tehillim 22:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.22.2?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi):

> אֵלִ֣י אֵ֭לִי לָמָ֣ה עֲזַבְתָּ֑נִי רָח֥וֹק מִֽ֝ישׁוּעָתִ֗י דִּבְרֵ֥י שַׁאֲגָתִֽי׃

The version of the song I've heard has a happy, empowering sort of tune ([can be heard here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K67JQNbNpdg), for example), which has always struck me as something very strange, in particular when it's supposed to be a Purim song. In Purim, yes, there was a "Hester Panim" ([for example](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pri_Tzadik%2C_Purim.4.1?vhe=Pri_Tzaddik,_Lublin,_1901&lang=bi)), Hashem hid His face from us, seemingly abandoning us - but from there we also saw the greatness of the miracle: We discovered that Hashem hadn't left us after all! Yet all the verse that's sung is just about Hashem leaving David/any person saying the chapter, nothing about Hashem returning to us! How does that relate to Purim?

Furthermore, I'm not quite certain how someone can sing about Hashem seemingly abandoning him. This may just be how I feel and not everyone can relate, but I've never felt abandoned chas v'shalom by Hashem. At times, yes, there may have been some distance, but I think that was more my fault. And yet this song is sung with great happiness and enthusiasm, as though people are happy that Hashem has abandoned them! That's something I'm currently unable to grasp. Why is this song a happy song?

To sum up:

1. What does this song have to do with Purim?
2. Why is this song supposedly happy?

Comment: See Megillah 15b (and 4a)

Comment: First question is answered [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23531/) - though I don’t think it’s a duplicate - and second question IMO is off-topic.

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks, I did not remember that gemara at all. Makes sense.

Comment: https://www.thetorah.com/article/my-god-my-god-why-have-you-forsaken-me-jesus-or-esther